# Delphi - ComboBox/LookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, combobox, lookup, delphi-xe7

I'm having a problem with ComboBox/LookupComboBox, It's something really idiot but I don't know how to search it through google to fix it.
I Have a table on my database who saves "Y/N" for a record to indicate if it's Active (Y) or Inactive (N).
But on my application I'd like to show to the user "YES/NO" and not just a single word, can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `ListSource` property of the `TDBLookupComboBox` combined with the `KeyField` and `ListField`. Map `KeyField` to Y or N and `ListField` to Yes or No, for that add 2 records to the `ListField's` DataSet, the first would be like Y - Yes the second like N - No. You could add both values at runtime, in the form create for example.

Comment: That's one of the problems, I don't want to create a listfield dataset, I remember trying once putting a pipeline or something on the Items of the Lookup for indicate KeyField and DisplayField but I don't remember how to do it anymore. Thanks for the repply

Comment: Use DBCheckBox then. As @SpeedFreak mentioned.

Comment: _I don't want to create a listfield dataset_. What is the technical problem with it?

Comment: The technical problem is that my boss didn't autorize me to do it :( Thanks for your help

Comment: That is not technical. There are 2 built in options for you `TDBCheckBox` or `TDBLookupComboBox`. Also, you can always come up with a new component to make things easier for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `TDBLookupComboBox` you need to specify two data sources. One specifies where the value is stored (`DataSource` and `DataField` properties) and the other specifies the lookup values (`ListSource`, `KeyField` and `ListField` properties). `DataField` and `KeyField` points to the columns containing the Y/N values and `ListField` points to the column containign the YES/NO values. You can use an in memory dataset, such as `TClientDataset`, for the lookup values.

Personally I would use a `TDBCheckBox` instead and set the `ValueChecked` and `ValueUnchecked` properties to 'Y' and 'N'. A checkbox much better represents a boolean value.

Comment: That's right. I would go with `TDBCheckBox` as well.